# ValueError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a list with name of organizations like this:

```
name = ['ALPHABET INC', 'AMAZON COM INC', 'APPLE INC',....]
```

and another list of cu values like this:

```
cu = ['02079K305', '023135106', '037833100',....]
```

When i'm trying to convert it to dataframe it's giving me error message saying, "ValueError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns"

My code to convert list ot dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([name, cu], columns=['name of issuer', 'cusip'])
```

Where am i going wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think simpliest is create dictionaries:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name of issuer': name, 'cusip':cu})
```

Your solution is possible with `zip`, in last version of pandas should be omit `list`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(name, cu)), columns=['name of issuer', 'cusip'])
```

---

```
print (df)
   name of issuer      cusip
0    ALPHABET INC  02079K305
1  AMAZON COM INC  023135106
2       APPLE INC  037833100
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `zip`

```
pd.DataFrame(zip(name, cu), columns=['name of issuer', 'cusip'])
```

ex:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(zip(name, cu), columns=['name of issuer', 'cusip'])
>>> df
   name of issuer      cusip
0    ALPHABET INC  02079K305
1  AMAZON COM INC  023135106
2       APPLE INC  037833100
```

Comment: Do not use zip blindly, it will truncate silently if lengths are unequal.

Answer (score 2):

Your structure of the list puts the data into rows rather than columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([name, cu]).T
df.columns = ['name of issuer', 'cusip']

>>> df
   name of issuer      cusip
0    ALPHABET INC  02079K305
1  AMAZON COM INC  023135106
2       APPLE INC  037833100
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, panda thinks the value you are passing is one large list. One way to change this is to pass in a dictionary as data with column names as keys and lists as values.

`df = pd.DataFrame({'name of issuer' : name, 'cusip' : cu})`