# How to split one string element in a list into two in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list

Sorry in advance if this is a silly question.

I need to use pandas to sort some data, but what I have been given is formatted strangely, and I get an error message "2 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns"

['Fred Green,20/11/2020\n', 'Jack Wilson,01/05/2021\n',] etc.

How can I go about splitting the elements into two at the , point, so I can get my columns to work properly?

Comment: hi, perhaps this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60751819/valueerror-2-columns-passed-passed-data-had-1-columns

Comment: Show the code that generates this error message.  Read the [mcve] guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use list-comprehension to split each string and then pass it to `pd.DataFrame`:

```
lst = ['Fred Green,20/11/2020\n', 'Jack Wilson,01/05/2021\n',]

df = pd.DataFrame([item.strip().split(',') for item in lst], columns=['name', 'date'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
          name        date
0   Fred Green  20/11/2020
1  Jack Wilson  01/05/2021
```